# Compute the curl

Tags: multivariable-calculus, mathematical-physics

Given that $\vec{\nabla}.{\vec{m}}=0$, and the vectors be in $\mathbb{R}^3$ I am trying to show that $$\vec{\nabla}\times \frac{r^2}{2}\vec{r}\times\vec{m}=(\vec{m}.\vec{r})\vec{r}-2r^2\vec{m}$$

I did 
$$\frac{r^2}{2}\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{r}\times\vec{m}=\frac{r^2}{2}(\vec{r}(\vec{\nabla}.\vec{m})-\vec{m}(\vec{\nabla}.\vec{r})-(\vec{r}.\vec{\nabla})\vec{m}+(\vec{m}.\vec{\nabla})\vec{r})$$
$$=\frac{r^2}{2}(\vec{m}.\vec{\nabla})\vec{r}-\frac{r^2}{2}\vec{m}(\vec{\nabla}.\vec{r})$$
It is also known that $\vec{\nabla}.\vec{r}=2$.
$$\frac{r^2}{2}(\vec{m}.\vec{\nabla})\vec{r}-r^2\vec{m}$$
But I could not get desired identity.

Comment: Isn't $\nabla \cdot \vec r = 3$ in $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: @RobertLewis nope.

Comment: So $\vec r \ne (x, y, z)$ then?

Comment: @RobertLewis see http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090915142404AAp1iQo

Comment: Read it.  So $\vec r$ is *unit* radial field then?

Comment: yes. it is. sorry for not mentioning previously.

Comment: Might want to edit you question a little, then . . .

Answer (score 1):

Your expressions need more parentheses than it has. Either way, let's start with the identity

$$\vec{A} \times (\vec{B} \times \vec{C}) = \vec{B} (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{C}) - \vec{C} (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B}).$$

Applying this to our expression gives

$$\nabla \times \left( \frac{r^2}{2} \vec{r} \times \vec{m} \right) = \vec{r} \left( \nabla \cdot \left( \frac{r^2}{2} \vec{m} \right) \right) - \vec{m} \left( \nabla \cdot \left( \frac{r^2}{2} \vec{r} \right) \right).$$

Expanding the RHS yields, for the first term,

$$\nabla \cdot \left( \frac{r^2}{2} \vec{m} \right) = \nabla \left( \frac{r^2}{2} \right) \cdot \vec{m} + \frac{r^2}{2} \nabla \cdot \vec{m} = \vec{r} \cdot \vec{m}.$$

The second term yields

$$\nabla \cdot \left( \frac{r^2}{2} \vec{r} \right) = \nabla \left( \frac{r^2}{2} \right) \cdot \vec{r} + \frac{r^2}{2} \nabla \cdot \vec{r} = \vec{r} \cdot \vec{r} + \frac{r^2}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{r} = r^2 + r.$$

This leads to

$$\nabla \times \left( \frac{r^2}{2} \vec{r} \times \vec{m} \right) = (\vec{m} \cdot \vec{r} ) \vec{r} - \vec{m}(r^2 +r).$$

For our desired expression we would need that one of the $r$'s didn't cancel, but that doesn't seem to be the case. That's because $\nabla \cdot \vec{r} = 2r^{-1}$, not just $2$.

It's not completely what we wanted, but it's pretty close. Maybe I have a calculation error somewhere.